# multiple regex matches in a string

Tags: java, regex

i have the following text:

```
bla [string1] bli [string2]
```

I like to match string1 and string2 with regex in a loop in java.

Howto do ?

my code so far, which only matches the first string1, but not also string 2.

```
String sRegex="(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sRegex); // create the pattern only once,
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sFormula);
        if (m.find()) 
        {
            String sString1 = m.group(0); 
            String sString2 = m.group(1); // << no match
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not using any captured groups hence this call with throw exceptions:

```
m.group(1);
```

You can use just use:

```
String sRegex="(?<=\\[)[^]]*(?=\\])";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sRegex); // create the pattern only once,
Matcher m = p.matcher(sFormula);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println( m.group() );
}
```

Also `if` should be replaced by `while` to match multiple times to return all matches.

Comment: Does not work for me . That is exactly my problem. Your code also only matches the first string. Howto do this for matching also the second string2? I like to have all matches for [?] in a string .

Comment: `if` should be replaced by `while` to match multiple times to return all matches.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks a lot. The problem is solved with your hint. kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is confused.  Either write your regex so that it matches two `[....]` sequences in the one pattern, or call `find` multiple times.  Your current attempt has a regex that "finds" just one `[...]` sequence.

Try something like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(formula);
    if (m.find()) {
        String string1 = m.group(0);
        if (m.find(m.end()) {
            String string2 = m.group(0);
        }
    }
```

Or generalize using a loop and an array of `String` for the extracted strings.

(You don't need any fancy look-behind patterns in this case.  And ugly "hungarian notation" is frowned in Java, so get out of the habit of using it.)

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Howto write the regex to match all [?] in a string. I tried your regex, but it throwed an error java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index. All I like is howto to get all string in brackeds of a big string. I don't know, thats why I ask :-)